# Avoiding repetitive sub-class definitions in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, header-files

I am new to C++ classes, and I have a question about defining multiple sub-classes of an abstract type/interface which would have identical definitions.

Take the following example which might appear in a header file with 3 sub-classes:

```
class Animal {
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    explicit Animal(int a) {}
    virtual Animal* getFriend() = 0;
    virtual bool walk() = 0;
    virtual bool talk() = 0;
    virtual bool someFunction() = 0;
    virtual bool someOtherFunction() = 0;
    // ... many more functions
}

class Zebra: public Animal {
    Animal* getFriend();
    bool walk();
    bool someFunction();
    bool someOtherFunction();
    // ... continues for many more functions
}

class Cow: public Animal {
    Animal* getFriend();
    bool walk();
    bool someFunction();
    bool someOtherFunction();
    // ... continues for many more functions
}

class Salmon: public Animal {
    Animal* getFriend();
    bool walk();
    bool someFunction();
    bool someOtherFunction();
    // ... continues for many more functions
}

// ... many more animals
```

Declaring the sub-classes like this seems repetitive and potentially error prone. Because the class definitions are identical except for the name of the class, is there a more efficient way to declare the animal sub-classes in bulk?

In the context I am working in each animal would have a completely independent implementation in separate `.cpp` files.

Please let me know if i'm approaching this completely wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of using a macro to define the classes (which is even worse!), there probably isn't a great deal you can do. Occasionally stuff like this might work, but I'd wager that at *some* point, you'd want to specialise one of the animals, leading to you ditching the macro again. It's for that reason I'd avoid that particular technique.

```cpp
#define DECLARE_ANIMAL(ANIMAL_TYPE) \
class ANIMAL_TYPE: public Animal { \
    Animal* getFriend() override; \
    bool walk() override; \
    bool someFunction() override; \
    bool someOtherFunction() override; \
};
DECLARE_ANIMAL(Zebra);
DECLARE_ANIMAL(Cow);
DECLARE_ANIMAL(Salmon);
```

Generally speaking, try to move as much of the duplicated class methods & data into the base class to minimise the amount of code duplication. This may require a slight change in the way you think about the problem though....

For example, walk(). In the case of a Cow/Zebra/Horse/Cat/Dog, the act of walking is pretty much identical. The only real differences can be measured with data *(e.g. the walk speed, how many legs are used, what is the gait of the walk, how large is each stride?)*. If you can define the behaviour in a data-driven fashion, you would just need to set those parameters in the Derived class constructor, and avoid the need for 
customised methods. Approaching the class design this way has a few other benefits, for example you'd have a single 'Dog' class, but it would be able to represent a 4 legged dog, and a 3 legged dog, without needing to create a new class.

That's usually the approach I'd recommend anyway...

Answer (score 5):

It *is* indeed error prone when you don't make use of the [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) keyword for each overridden virtual class member function.

Instead of declaring the derived class function like this

```
bool someFunction();
```

you can/should declare it like this

```
bool someFunction() override;
```

In this way, you would get a compilation error if the declaration doesn't match the base class signature. Without it, you would have a perfectly good compilable program but with a behaviour bug.

Other than that, your strategy is fine, and is the way to do handle abstract functions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing another answer as an alternative solution. Actually, If i faced with same 'issue' or 'problem', i would not declare as bulk, I would just create `zebra.h`, `zebra.cpp`, inherits from `Animal` and declare/define all members individually. In other words i would prefer not to be clever but if you want to be the piece of codes below could be an alternative.

Indeed, you just want to create a class declaration from a template. That's what `template` is doing. It is possible to mimic same behaviour with `MACRO`s but I would prefer `template` rather than `MACRO` because it is what Bjarne did.

So here is the code

**animal.h**

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

class Animal {
private:
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    explicit Animal(int a) {}
    virtual ~Animal() = default; // You should this virtual destructor
                                 // for polymorphic types.
    virtual Animal* getFriend() = 0;
    virtual bool walk() = 0;
    virtual bool talk() = 0;
    virtual bool someFunction() = 0;
    virtual bool someOtherFunction() = 0;
};

enum class animal_types
{
    zebra ,
    cow ,
    salmon ,
    special_animal
};

template< animal_types >
struct ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor : Animal
{
    using Animal::Animal; // Use parent constructor as is
    Animal* getFriend() override;
    bool walk() override;
    bool talk() override;
    bool someFunction() override;
    bool someOtherFunction() override;
};


using Zebra = ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor< animal_types::zebra >;
using Cow = ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor< animal_types::cow >;
using Salmon = ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor< animal_types::salmon >;

// So on..

#include "zebra.h"
#include "salmon.h"
#include "cow.h"
#include "special_animal.h"

#endif // ANIMAL_H
```

**cow.h**

```
#ifndef COW_H
#define COW_H

#include "animal.h"

template<>
Animal* Cow::getFriend() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<>
bool Cow::walk() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Cow::talk() {
    return false;
}

template<>
bool Cow::someFunction() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Cow::someOtherFunction() {
    return true;
}

#endif // COW_H
```

**salmon.h**

```
#ifndef SALMON_H
#define SALMON_H

#include "animal.h"

template<>
Animal* Salmon::getFriend() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<>
bool Salmon::walk() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Salmon::talk() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Salmon::someFunction() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Salmon::someOtherFunction() {
    return true;
}

#endif // SALMON_H
```

**zebra.h**

```
#ifndef ZEBRA_H
#define ZEBRA_H

#include "animal.h"

template<>
Animal* Zebra::getFriend() {
    return nullptr;
}

template<>
bool Zebra::walk() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Zebra::talk() {
    return false;
}

template<>
bool Zebra::someFunction() {
    return true;
}

template<>
bool Zebra::someOtherFunction() {
    return true;
}

#endif // ZEBRA_H
```

**special_animal.h**

```
#ifndef SPECIAL_ANIMAL_H
#define SPECIAL_ANIMAL_H

#include "animal.h"
#include <iostream>

template<>
struct ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor<animal_types::special_animal> : Animal
{
    using Animal::Animal; // Use parent constructor as is
    Animal* getFriend() override { return nullptr; }
    bool walk() override { return true; }
    bool talk() override { return true; }
    bool someFunction() override { return true; }
    bool someOtherFunction() override { return true; }

    void specility_fn() {
        std::cout << "A speciality" << std::endl;
    }

private:

    int some_extra_member;
    // etc..

};

using special_animal = ugly_bulk_animal_inheritor<animal_types::special_animal>;

#endif // SPECIAL_ANIMAL_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "animal.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Animal* instance;
    Zebra z { 5 };
    Cow c  { 6 };
    Salmon t { 7 };

    instance = &z;
    std::cout << "Zebra can talk ? " << instance->talk() << std::endl;
    instance = &t;
    std::cout << "Salmon can talk ? " << instance->talk() << std::endl;

    special_animal s { 5 };
    s.specility_fn();

    return 0;
}
```