# How to describe the inherited class?

Tags: c++, templates, derived-class, base-class

I have one Base and *many* (1..N) Derived classes like that:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) = 0;
}

class Derived_1: public Base {
public:
  void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) override;
}

class Derived_2: public Base {
public:
  void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) override;
}

void Derived_1::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {actions 1};
void Derived_2::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {actions 2};
```

All derived classes have the *same definition* but *different* OnMouseMove() functions.
I do not like how the program looks, because I have to write in header files all the same derived functions only with different names Derived_1, Derived_2.

Is it possible to write program shorter? I need something like that:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
  void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) override;
}

class Derived_1 : public Derived{};
class Derived_2 : public Derived{};

void Derived_1::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {actions 1};
void Derived_2::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {actions 1};
```

Comment: No, it's not possible. Also that's saving you 2 lines per class, is this really worth it?

Comment: Maybe, you could look at my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60258003/3421515), it could be beneficial.

Comment: Not very important, only interesting. There are a lot of function in derived class like OnMouseDown() and so on. I just like when the code looks beautiful.

Comment: This may be a case for a legit macro use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using templates in that case like this one:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) = 0;
};  

template < int N>
class Derived: public Base {
public:
  void OnMouseMove(int x, int y) override;
};

template<> void Derived<1>::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {std::cout<< "1"<< std::endl;}
template<> void Derived<2>::OnMouseMove(int x, int y) {std::cout<< "2"<< std::endl;}

int main()
{
    Base* ptr1 = new Derived<1>;
    Base* ptr2 = new Derived<2>;

    ptr1->OnMouseMove(5,6);
    ptr2->OnMouseMove(5,6);
}
```

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica: If you have a compiler you can test it :-) My one did what I expect... ( gcc 9.2.1 & clang 9.0.0).